# iTunes archive on non permanent external drive?

Tags: itunes, external-disk

Is it possible or recommended to have the iTunes library on a non-permanent external drive? What will happen if I e.g. sync my iPhone while the drive is not attached? Or what will happen when iTunes thinks it should download the music I have bought on my iPad while the drive is not connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. In fact, I manage my family's iPod this way.

- The howto is answered in [How to move iTunes’ Mobile Applications folder to an external hard drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51146/how-to-move-itunes-mobile-applications-folder-to-an-external-hard-drive). **Shut down iTunes, move your library, then start iTunes back up while holding down Option. Tell it you will choose a library, then show it your library on your drive.** For more advanced library management, see [Can I keep my iTunes library on an external drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14353/can-i-keep-my-itunes-library-on-an-external-drive).
- As for your concerns, always shut down iTunes before removing your drive. I don't know what will happen if you unplug it without killing iTunes.
- If you try to bring up iTunes without your drive plugged in, you will see these two dialogs, one after the other: 
  [image]
  [image]
  In the first one, simply click OK to get the second one, then quit, plug in your drive, and try again. **If iTunes can't find your library, it will not try to sync your iPhone or download purchased music.**